# Remote web server cant send email by my ASP.NET 4 applicaiton

Tags: asp.net, smtpclient

My site has some functionality to send email to user some perspective. I have done this. My method can sending email successfully when i am running this application from Visual Studio or  My local IIS 7 server (I Configured My PC). But the remote online web server can't send email. Please give me some tips how can i solve this issue. I have already gave lot of time to google but not found this solution. My code

```
const string fromAddress = "ejobsbdinfo@gmail.com";
const string fromPassword = "password";
string toAddress = account.Email;
string subject = "subject";
string body = "mail Body";
var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
{
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
    smtp.Timeout = 20000;
}
smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
```

give me some instruction how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when doing the send?

Comment: What error you get. i guess, it's probably because of the network-credentials you passing.